# Networking Multiple PCs and using all their processing power for one program

Tags: networking, cpu, process, combine, multiple-computers

I would like to use a set of networked computers to work out some processes which would normally take long to do on one. I figured that it might be done faster with networked PCs.

These PCs are all using Intel based processors (though if I can do it with other architectures, it would be better). Also they are all running windows (though again, it would be better if it can be done on different OSs, these are since I do have another PC with linux on it).

I have searched however all the results say is that it's possible, but not how. I don't mind if it's complicated, at least I'll know how.

These PCs can be networked using a Wired LAN or Wireless LAN, probably with both though.

Also, I am aware that there is another question like this, however I feel the answer lacked what I was looking for.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like to know if there is a program (preferably windows though now linux works too) to combine the processing power of my computers so that long processes can be split between them to be worked in parallel.

Comment: You can only do it if the process you are trying to do was designed to do this. Exactly what are you trying to do and which software are you currently using? Also what was the other question that you felt lacked, and what lacked about it? If you don't tell us we are likely to give you the same "lacking" answer again.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to link it. here it is: http://superuser.com/questions/122506/is-it-possible-to-combine-processing-power-of-2-computers/. Aslo, I can't say what processes I have. Sorry. Is there an in general way to do this? If not, can you give me some examples? Thanks

Comment: If you were using Linux, [Mosix](http://www.mosix.org/faq/output/faq_flat.html) **might** have been worth looking at. The project *might* be worth looking at just to get a sense of some of the issues involved.

Comment: Well I can use linux not a problem

Comment: @markscamilleri You're edit makes this into a simple Product Request, which are off-topic.  You're ignoring what people are telling you.  You need to describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish, instead of requesting a way to vaguely combine the processing power of multiple PCs. As=-is, you question is no different than [the one you linked](http://superuser.com/questions/122506/is-it-possible-to-combine-processing-power-of-2-computers?lq=1).

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/647132/linking-computers-to-increase-performance?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/647132/linking-computers-to-increase-performance?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/688784/networking-multiple-pcs-and-using-all-their-processing-power-for-one-program?lq=1

Comment: You could look into [Clustering for ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Clustering) or [OpenStack Compute](http://www.openstack.org/software/openstack-compute/) , though the latter can only be done with virtual machines. Either way you're trying to do something that is A) remarkably difficult B) remarkably expensive C) impractical, as programs would have to be specifically written to support it

Comment: ok, thanks, so shall I just delete the question then or leave it here?

Comment: I posted a new answer to the old [Is it possible to combine the processing power of two computers?](http://superuser.com/q/122506/150988) question.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact you will not tell us what software you are trying to run the best answer we can give you is: *You can't do what you want to do unless the software you are using has that feature built in to it already.*

If you would be willing to tell us what software you are trying to use we could tell you if the software supports distributed computing and how to use it.

Comment: ok, thanks. It's not that I don't want to, it's just that I can't. Sorry