# Is there a way to build cluster machine that behaves like a single PC?

Tags: performance, cluster

Is there some way to build a cluster from several desktops in such a way, that it can run an unprepared application and be seen as just a multicore CPU?
I understand it will be a lot slower than running Beowulf with a prepared MPI calculation, but we have no sources of the app we want to run on cluster. It just uses posix-multithreading. 
Anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to combine processing power of 2 computers?](http://superuser.com/questions/122506/is-it-possible-to-combine-processing-power-of-2-computers)

Comment: I am asking exactly how to avoid solutions offered in that question

Answer (score 2):

If that is a Linux program, the [Kerrighed](http://www.kerrighed.org/) patches on Linux 2.6.30 can be used to create a Linux [single system image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image) cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard... If the app itself doesn't have the ability for outsourcing, then we can do nothing.

But maybe you can explore an alternative way. For example, if the function of your app is to process some input and generate some output, why not just dividing the input into multiple groups and distribute them over multiple machines?